# jquery radio button getting value not option ID

Tags: jquery, radio-button, smarty

I'm using the E-Commerce-Shop-System xtmodified v1.06d. Some of my products do habe some attributes (different sizes), which can be chosen via radio-button.

The code used to display these attributes is the following:

```
{foreach key=key_data item=item_data from=$options_data.DATA}

{if $options_data.NAME == 'Dateiupload'}{$item_data.DESCRIPTION}

<input data-attrdata="{$item_data.JSON_ATTRDATA}" type="radio" name="id[{$options_data.ID}]" value="{$item_data.ID}" />

{else}
<strong>{$item_data.TEXT}</strong><br />{$item_data.DESCRIPTION}

{/if}

{/foreach}
```

What I want to achieve is on click on one of the radio buttons the chosen attribute should get shown.

For this I tried to use this jquery-code:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on("change", function() {
    $("#info .filevalue").text(this.value);
});
```

The value gets displayed in a div:

```
<div id="info">
You chosen format
   <span class="filevalue">file value goes here</span>
</div>
```

But the only thing I get is the option-Id of the radio-button I clicked, but not the value which states the chosen format.

I have to admit that I don't know in which format the wanted data is given...I think it's JSON...

Any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: so this is the part that is confusing you? `value="{$item_data.ID}"`

Comment: Hi ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ...that's what I'm getting in my div, when I click one of the radio-buttons...but I want this to be displayed: **{$item_data.TEXT}**

Comment: the first section of code you are displaying is smarty http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: can you just change `value="{$item_data.ID}"` to `value="{$item_data.TEXT}"`?  Or do you have a need to set the value to `{$item_data.ID}`

Comment: wow, this solved my problem, I think! Need to test it a bit further, but it looks great at the moment! Thx a lot ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ!

Comment: {$item_data.TEXT} is a variable assignment from smarty are you try to litteraly put "{$item_data.TEXT}" into the output ?

Comment: mcgrailm: I don't know exactly what you mean, but I think you're right...but problem is solved...thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but **{$item_data.TEXT}** its not in your radio button, its in the else part..=? put it on an data- Attribute on the input, then you can get it..

```
<input data-something="{$item_data.TEXT}" data-attrdata="{$item_data.JSON_ATTRDATA}" type="radio" name="id[{$options_data.ID}]" value="{$item_data.ID}" />

$('input[type=radio]').on("change", function() {
    $("#info .filevalue").text($(this).attr("data-something"));
});
```

Comment: this works as well, thx a lot! but I used the solution of ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ!, I changed this line only: '<input data-attrdata="{$item_data.JSON_ATTRDATA}" type="radio" name="id[{$options_data.ID}]" value="{$item_data.TEXT}" />'

Comment: after some testing I found out that my chosen solution above doesn't work properly! but your's seems to work fine! Thx again!